# Formatting a distorted python data frame

Tags: pandas

Is there a direct method to set rows of a distorted table in corresponding order?

Herewith I have attached an snapshot of the distortion.

[image: Table here]

Answer (score 0):

here is a way to read your excel file if i understand your question correctly

```
df = pd.read_excel('path\filename.xlsx',sheet_name='name of your sheet name')
df.columns = ['col_name','values']
temp_1_df = df['col_name'].copy()
temp_1_df.dropna(inplace=True)
temp_2_df = df['values'].copy()
temp_2_df.dropna(inplace=True)
result = pd.concat([temp_1_df,temp_2_df], axis=1)
```

Comment: @Vilochanabandara ...you are most welcome...One way to say thanks in stackoverflow is give an upvote to the answer or accepting the answer ...This will give points to the user who answered the question..Cheers :) glad it helped